# Find attribute name by value in BeautifulSoup (not reverse)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to automatically find the attribute name when knowing a unique value I'd be searching for in BeautifulSoup.

E.g.

```
>>> soup = '<div class="bla">123</div>'
```

"Knowing" `123`, how would we get the output `"bla"`?

the opposite would simply be:

```
>>> soup.find("bla")
123
```

to get the value of the attribute "bla", but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this section of the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all):

```
for e in soup.find_all(text='123'):
    print(e.parent['class'])
```

We find all elements with the text of `123`, and get the parent's CSS class.